# Symmetric line spaces are homeomorphic to Euclidean spaces

Tags: reference-request, gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry

For points $x,y,z$ of a metric space $(X,d)$ we write $\mathbf Mxyz$ and say that $y$ is a *midpoint* between $x$ and $z$ if $d(x,z)=d(x,y)+d(y,z)$ and $d(x,y)=d(y,z)$.

**Definition:** A metric space $(X,d)$ is called

$\bullet$ *medial* if for any points $a,b\in X$ there exist unique points $x,y\in X$ such that $\mathbf Maxb$ and $\mathbf Maby$;

$\bullet$ *symmetric* if $\forall a,b,c,\alpha,\beta\in X\quad(\mathbf Mac\alpha\wedge \mathbf Mbc\beta)\Rightarrow d(a,b)=d(\alpha,\beta)$;

$\bullet$ a *line space* if $(X,d)$ is nonempty, medial and every bounded sequence in $X$ has a convergent subsequence.

It can be shown that for any distinct points $a,b\in X$ of a medial complete metric space $(X,d)$ there exists a unique isometric embedding $f:\mathbb R\to X$ such that $f(0)=a$ and $f(d(a,b))=b$. This fact implies that  line metric spaces are [Busemann G-spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busemann_G-space) (but not vice versa).

> **Example:** Every strictly convex finite-dimensional Banach space is a symmetric line space (and is homeomorphic to a Euclidean space $\mathbb R^n$).

The famous Busemann Conjecture claims that every Busemann G-space is a topological manifold.  This conjecture is known to be true for Busemann G-spaces of topological dimension $\le 4$.

On the other hand, for symmetric line spaces the Busemann Conjecture seems to be true for all dimensions and in the following stronger form:

> **Conjecture:** Every symmetric line space is homeomorphic to a Euclidean space $\mathbb R^n$.

I strongly believe that this Conjecture is true and can be derived from the known theory of homogeneous spaces of Lie groups and [the Cartan classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_space) of symmetric Riemannian manifolds. Nonetheless, I cannot find a precise reference in the literature.

So, my question:

> **Question.** Is the Conjecture indeed true? And if yes, what is a proper reference?

**Remark:** The Conjecture is true if the answer to [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/443731/61536) (on contractible homogeneous spaces of Lie groups) is affirmative.

Concerning the "non-symmetric" version of the Conjecture, I am not so optimistic, so ask it as an open

> **Problem:** Is every line metric space homeomorphic to a Euclidean space?

**Added in Edit:** According to the answer of Shijie Gu to [this problem](https://mathoverflow.net/q/443731/61536), the Conjecture is indeed true, so the Question has an affirmative answer. Only the Problem remains open (up to  my current knowldge). Since this problem is a modification of the Busemann Conjecture which is true for Busemann G-spaces of small dimension, I expect that the answer to Problem is affirmative at least for spaces of small topological dimension, say $\le 4$.

Comment: I am confused by the definition. Certainly uniqueness in "medial" points out to a more restrictive definition of midpoints (adding $d(x,y)=d(y,z)$ maybe?), right?

Comment: I do not think Cartan is relevant here, but Montgomery-Zippin et al should do the job. But maybe you'll have to add the assumption of finite dimension.

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner Thank you for the comment. Indeed, I forgot to add this equality, which is added now.

Comment: @MoisheKohan As far as I can understand, Montgomery-Zippin can help in proving that the symmetric Busemann G-space is a homogeneous space $G/H$ of a Lie group $G$, so has a structure of a smooth manifold. But how to prove (from Montgometry-Zippin) that it is homeomorphic to an Euclidean space? Exactly for this task I had an idea to apply Cartan's classification of symmetric spaces. Finite dimension should follow from the compactness of closed balls in the symmetry of a Busemann G-space, namely, from the local compactness of its isometry group.

Comment: It is still unclear to me how to get finite dimension (I am worried about some versions of the Hilbert-cube-manifolds). I do not see how one can use Cartan in your setting since he only classifies Riemannian symmetric spaces.

Comment: @MoisheKohan By the assumption, the space is isometrically homogeneous and bounded subsets are compact. Those assumptions imply that its isometry group is locally compact. So the space is a quotient space of a locally compact group, and being locally contractible, is a topological manifold, by a result of Szenthe or Hoffmann or Antonyan (there were three different proofs of the same result of Szenthe whose proof contained a gap). And topological manifolds are finite-dimensional. Of course, this fact is neither obvious nor trivial, but true nonetheless.

Comment: @TarasBanakh: I see. I did not know this theorem, my knowledge of topological transformation groups is limited to the results before 1960s.